# Is any body making a windows replacement to msysgit with libgit2,libgit2sharp, Ngit?

Tags: windows, git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

Hi I like Git but it seems sharing windows projects with people and friends is  not fun because gitextensions tortoisegit are ugly to use out of the box compared to tortoisehg or tortoisesvn (not that it's DVCS).
Using msysgit just in a bash shell doesn't make it as nice as linux/Mac either.

So **is there any new contenders (alpha projects etc(even with other libs))?**

I would love to see these new Git libraries take off!

Comment: If you think msysgit is fine well I more agree with this guy http://stackoverflow.com/a/2575991/790359

Comment: But that aside please just tell me if new lib based git's are being developed **that is my question** I don't care who likes what.

Comment: Little offtopic, but if you want good GUI-based Windows Git-client, **you have to see** at SmartGit (Java, but - who cares?)

Comment: @LazyBadger Yeah it's awesome for a pay for commercial use (nothing beats it), they currently support msysgit on windows (not cygwin so much etc) I think.

Comment: You said noting originally about commercial vs non-commercial usage, and Syntevo have *reasonable price*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After having released **[Github for Mac](https://desktop.github.com/)**, there are rumors that Github *might* be working on a client for Windows.

See those tweets below for reference:

- https://twitter.com/#!/aeoth/statuses/170808010904580096
- https://twitter.com/#!/xpaulbettsx/statuses/174351777230102528
- https://twitter.com/#!/MotoWilliams/statuses/180329291622526977
- https://jp.twitter.com/#!/Mpdreamz/status/177648471057235968
- https://twitter.com/#!/lazycoder/status/177638341112635394
- https://twitter.com/#!/xpaulbettsx/status/177648557489270785

According to this last **[one](https://twitter.com/#!/xpaulbettsx/status/177638536684638209)**, there are good chances [libgit2sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) & [libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2) would be used to help run the client.

## Update

- **[Github for windows](https://desktop.github.com/)** has been released. See this **[post](https://github.blog/2012-05-21-github-for-windows/)** for further information. Among other open source libraries and software, it indeed relies on libgit2 and LibGit2Sharp.

[image: github-for-windows]

- A work in progress, **[Git GUI](https://github.com/kaisellgren/Git-GUI)**, by Kai Sellgren, also relies on those libs

[image: Git-GUI]

Comment: Awesome I hope it come through!

Comment: http://warpspire.com/posts/designing-github-mac/ seems like it's made with libgit2 (not mentioned on http://libgit2.github.com/ yet if it's true)

Comment: Is github for mac going to support mac  users push/pulling repos on the mac? or is it just for git hub :S

Comment: Github for Mac is designed to work with GitHub but can be used with any Git server. It's based on [Objective-Git](https://github.com/libgit2/objective-git) which are Objective-C bindings to libgit2

Comment: github for windows has been released, but it seems that we can only pull from and push to github.....

Comment: @Codest This is incorrect. The **[help page](http://windows.github.com/help.html)** states *"GitHub for Windows is optimized to work with GitHub remotes — but if you wish to use a non-GitHub remote, it will work just fine."*

Answer (score 1):

[GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/).

Here's the [launch blog post](https://github.com/blog/1127-github-for-windows).